# Passing messages from subclass to original WndProc

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I have been reading the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997565.aspx) documentation on subclassing and I have been successful in  handling events in a subclass

My issue is with passing messages back to the original WndProc.

As an example, if I have a window, with a sub-classed groupbox control and a button as a child of that groupbox, I want to handle the button event in the original window procedure, not the subclassed groupbox procedure.

Essentially, I want an empty subclass procedure:

```
LRESULT FAR PASCAL SubClassFunc(HWND hwnd,
                        UINT uMsg,
                WPARAM wParam,
                LPARAM lParam)
{
    return CallWindowProc(oldProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Where oldProc is:

```
FARPROC oldProc = (FARPROC)SetClassLong(group_box, GCL_WDPROC, (DWORD)SubCLassFunc);
```

And where the window and groupbox and button are:

```
HWND window = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE, 
    appname,
    TEXT("Subclass Test"),
    WS_VISIBLE |WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    300,
    400,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    0);

HWND group_box = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    TEXT("BUTTON"),
    TEXT("Group Box"),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX,
    8,
    8,
    275,
    350,
    window,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    0);

HWND push_button = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    TEXT("BUTTON"),
    TEXT("Push Button"),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_VCENTER,
    50,
    100,
    100,
    25,
    group_box,
    (HMENU)PUSH_BUTTON,
    hInstance,
    0);
```

I can handle the button events in the SubClassFunc, but what I want to do is pass them back to the window WndProc. It seems that CallWindowProc isn't doing this, or I may be totally wrong in how CallWindowProc works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button notifications are sent to the button's parent, which is the group box. Because you've subclassed the group box, your `SubClassFunc` receives these messages, which then passes them to the group box's original window procedure using `CallWindowProc`.

If you want the button notifications to go to the parent window (i.e, `window` in your code), you could either set the button's parent to `window` instead of `group_box`, or use `PostMessage` from within `SubClassFunc` to post the message (`WM_COMMAND` or `WM_NOTIFY` as appropriate) to `window`.

Also, I see that you're using `SetClassLong` to set the window procedure. What this does is replace the window procedure for the entire `BUTTON` class, but only for windows that are subsequently created. Any `BUTTON` windows created before calling `SetClassLong` will not be subclassed. You may want to consider using `SetWindowLong` instead, to subclass individual windows rather than the entire class.

Edit: The group box's original window procedure doesn't send `WM_COMMAND` messages to its parent. This is explained in Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) book:

> The group box, which has the `BS_GROUPBOX` style, is an oddity in the button class. It neither processes mouse or keyboard input, nor sends `WM_COMMAND` messages to its parent.

You should find that button notifications don't get through to `window` even if you don't subclass the group box.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you remove the subclass all together the button events will still not reach the original window procedure as you expect.

Since you have an subclass procedure doing nothing more than calling **CallWindowProc** the window is effectively not subclasses.

My suggestion would be to use the **Spy++** tool to see which window is getting the button event messages.

One of the more difficult aspects of Win32 programming is determining which window gets which message and **Spy++** is invaluable when it comes to figuring out this information.